# Adding two words sometimes misbehaves because of CBW instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, byte, cpu-word, tasm

**What I need**

Part of the program I am requested to write is an addition. The thing is that we are requested to define *bytes* and the convert them to *words* (**signed extension**) and only afterwards add them.

**The problem**

The addition sometimes does not give the desired output. For example, I am using the following:

```
data segment
    first     DB    183
    second    DB    94
data ends

code segment
start:

    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax

    mov AX, 0
    mov AL, first
    cbw

    mov BX, AX
    mov AX, 0

    mov AL, second
    cbw

    add AX, BX

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

code ends
end start
```

94 (*5E in hex*) + 183 (*B7 in hex*) = 277 (*115 in hex*), but because of the first `cbw`, *AX = FFB7* instead of *B7*. However, the second number remains *AX = 5E* as expected, so adding the two results in *AX = 15* with *CF = 1*.

I found [this page about CBW](http://www.ousob.com/ng/masm/ng64ce.php) where it states that "This instruction will set AH to 0FFh if the sign bit (bit 7) of AL is set", which is my case, because *B7* is *1011 0111* in binary.

Am I missing something? Should I interpret the carry flag in some way? Why am I not obtaining *115 (hex)* ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two ways of extending a byte to a word: sign-extending (for signed values, which is what `cbw` does), and zero-extending (for unsigned values). Which one are you supposed to do?

Comment: Signed, I should have specified this. Actually, I need to do both but I managed easily with the zero-extending operation

Comment: If they are signed, 0x15 is the correct result. `0xB7` equals `-73` when viewed as a signed byte, and `94 - 73 = 21 (0x15)`.

Comment: @Michael Damn, that was so obvious. If you could please add this as an answer, I can mark it as the correct one. Thanks!

Comment: @RaulRene - friendly reminder -- link-only answers are not allowed on Stack Overflow, as indicated by the possible delete reason in the Low Quality Review queue.  [This review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4147598#./4147598?&_suid=139325709875807189133743354755) was invalid, the 5 other delete votes have been invalidated, and now the answer will be flagged for moderator attention.  I've seen you approve a number of link-only answers today, so please be more mindful when reviewing in the future.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Thank you for pointing that. I am usually mindful when reviewing on SO, and I will try to be even more so in the future to avoid such mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 94 (5E in hex) + 183 (B7 in hex) = 277 (115 in hex), but because of the first cbw, AX = FFB7 instead of B7. However, the second number remains AX = 5E as expected, so adding the two results in AX = 15 with CF = 1. ...  Why am I not obtaining 115 (hex)

The result depends on whether the values should be viewed as signed or unsigned.

For signed, you should fill the upper byte with the most significant bit of the lower byte. This can be done with the `MOVSX` instruction (e.g. `MOVSX AX,AL`) or with `CBW` (`CBW` only works if the operand is in `AL`).

The byte `0xB7` sign-extended to a word equals `-73` (`0xFFB7`). So the expected result is `94 - 73 = 21 (0x15)`.

---

For unsigned, you should clear the upper byte. This can be done with the `MOVZX` instruction (e.g. `MOVZX AX,AL`) or by XOR:ing the upper byte with itself (e.g. `XOR AH,AH`).

The byte `0xB7` zero-extended to a word equals `183` (`0x00B7`). So the expected result is `94 + 183 = 277 (0x115)`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `cbw` you can use the zero-extended move `movzx AX, AL`.

You don't need to store the bytes in `AL` register when using `movzx` instruction. An optimal code could read:

```
mov AL, first
movzx AX, AL

mov BL, second
movzx BX, BL

add AX, BX
```

**Edit** Thanks to Jester for his suggestion to optimize the code further by exploiting the possibility of using memory variable in `movzx`:

```
movzx AX,byte ptr [first]
movzx BX,byte ptr [second]
add AX, BX
```

Comment: `movzx` works fine with memory operands, so `movzx ax, first; movzx bx, second; add ax, bx` is simpler. Slightly better code would be `mov al, first; add al, second; setc ah` (but apparently that's not allowed by the assignment).

Comment: I am guessing that `movzx` does something similar to `mov ah, 0`, but I need *signed* conversion. I am guessing that this isn't signed, right?
It's my fault, I should have specified that we are requested to use `cbw` because I need signed extension

Comment: I found the "pair" instruction for signed extension, which is `movsx`, but this gives me a *Illegal instruction for currently selected processor(s)* - tried in DOSBOX on Windows8 and on OSX Mountain Lion

Comment: movsx was introduced with the 386, you'll need to add the appropriate assembler directive to let it know you want to use 386 instructions.  ".386" is a common directive that works on several assemblers.